# Обработка строк в Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Следующая проблема, переводили файл из txt  в csv/excel. Получилось на выходе так, что одно значение разбилось по строкам и в эскеле одно значение растянулось на три, поэтому дальнейшая фильтрация не применима. Можно ли как то объединить эти строки?

Файл выглядит следующий образом:

```
4   08.07.14    17  900 08.07.14        706
                        Плата за перевод ю/л ,уд в руб
                        
5   08.07.14    17  901 08.07.14        706
                        Плата за перевод ю/л ,уд в руб
                        
6   08.07.14    17  898 08.07.14        7060
                        Комиссия по опер. с наличными
```

Нужно соответственно сделать все это без пропусков, и если длинный текст, то в рамках одной строки

[image: Приложил пример]

Comment: из вопроса не понята структура файла. можете вставить просто текст из csv?

Comment: я скинул из экселя, csv кодировка слетает почему то

Comment: вы скинули из экселя и теперь не понятна структура таблицы. хотябы поля разделите какими-то знаками

Comment: приложил скрин как выглядит эксель

Comment: выложили бы уже csv-файл на файлообменник.

Comment: кодировка слетела, а в экселе конфиденциальные данные, не могу(

Comment: Вам помощь действительно нужна, или так, поговорить? Если нужна - то вырезаете из своего суперсекретного файла некоторый фрагмент и показываете.  А иначе - ничего непонятно. Какое значение разбилось, какое растянулось? А пустые строки -  они откуда взялись??  И вообще, может лучше покажете исходный txt (фрагмент его), а не инвалидный сvs? Может так проще будет навести порядок в ваших секретах?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку на вопросы вы не отвечаете, вот вам вариант:

```
import csv   
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')

with open('nt.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
    for i,line in enumerate(txtfile.readlines()):
        if i%3==0:
            n_line=line.split()
        if i%3==1:
            n_line=n_line+[line.strip()]
            writer.writerow(n_line)
        else:
            pass
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если что не так, надеюсь протюнинговать под ваши конкретные условия сможете самостоятельно.